# Why Inline Javascript is executed without error when Content-Security-Policy header is defined but not inline-script directive

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

According to the [CSP website](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-script/), `When you have a Content-Security-Policy header defined, the browser will automatically block inline scripts`.

However after removing all my other directives just left with `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https: http:`, my inline script is executed without error, why is that?

What I expect is my browser should block any inline javascript to run. Then that is where nonce, hashes and unsafe-inline comes in.

My inline javascript

```
<script>
  function test() {
    console.log("inline javascript is executed")
  }

  test();
</script>
```

[image]

CSP Browser Test (Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (x86_64)
)

[image]

Safari Test Result gives me correct errors but Chrome will run inline scripts without errors
[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you verified that the browser fully supports the notation you're using? Have you tried other browsers? Do you have a sample link to test?

Comment: I can't find any info on this, so I'm just putting out an idea here.  That script you have put out on it's own is not insecure.  But it would only become insecure once the DOM has been touched, IOW: Once it's become dirty.  So I wonder if the browser doesn't do a CSP check until the DOM has had some dynamic update, as that's were the potential for an XSS attack would happen.

Comment: @Michael, it's Chrome, see my updated screenshot, I will put a link later

Comment: Ok, my inline script runs without any error in Chrome, but Safari does block inline script as expected  see updated screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've put this small PHP file on my local xampp for testing...

first two notations are blocking the alert and the last allows it.
Tested on

- Chrome v103.0.5060.114 x64
- Edge 103.0.1264.49 x64
- Firefox 102.0.1 x64.

All browsers create an error message on the console that the inline execution of a script has been blocked because of CSP.

```
<?php
// no alert
//header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' http: https:", true);
// no alert
header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'", true);
// alert
//header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'", true);
?><html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<script>alert('test');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Troubleshooting ideas:

- Check the console if there CSP header is recognized or if there are unprintable chars or other syntax errors
- Are there browser addons that are modifying incoming headers
- Is there a security software running that is modifying incoming headers
- Is a proxy server blocking the headers

Comment: Confirmed it's my browser, it's still unclear why but it works after I switch to another chrome profile. Browser addons are disabled so not really an issue, thx for the help